# SQL min/max date from a history table by status grouping

Tags: sql, informix

This query is to display the data I want to work with:

```
SELECT
   nenh_entity
  ,nenh_trans_date
  ,nenh_trans_time
  ,nenh_trans_date*10000000+nenh_trans_time
  ,nenh_new_status_6
FROM
  ntcenh
;
nenh_entity   nenh_trans_date  nenh_trans_time  (expression)           nenh_new_status_6
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
EDNSB002      20180808         201230           201808080201230        SCHED DT           
EDNSB002      20180723         104731           201807230104731        STANDBY            
EDNSB002      20180723         101747           201807230101747        STANDBY            
EDNSB002      20180723         83237            201807230083237        STANDBY            
EDNSB002      20180723         80252            201807230080252        STANDBY            
EDNSB002      20180723         62250            201807230062250        STANDBY            
EDNSB002      20180723         55311            201807230055311        STANDBY            
EDNSB002      20180723         54329            201807230054329        STANDBY            
EDNSB002      20180723         51354            201807230051354        STANDBY            
EDNSB002      20180723         44208            201807230044208        PRODUCTIVE         
EDNSB002      20180723         42728            201807230042728        PRODUCTIVE         
EDNSB002      20180723         40551            201807230040551        PRODUCTIVE         
EDNSB002      20180723         35112            201807230035112        PRODUCTIVE         
EDNSB002      20180723         31912            201807230031912        PRODUCTIVE         
EDNSB002      20180723         31138            201807230031138        STANDBY            
EDNSB002      20180723         23411            201807230023411        STANDBY            
EDNSB002      20180723         21546            201807230021546        STANDBY            
EDNSB002      20180723         13707            201807230013707        PRODUCTIVE         
EDNSB002      20180723         11322            201807230011322        PRODUCTIVE         
EDNSB002      20180723         5414             201807230005414        PRODUCTIVE
```

What I want the SQL to produce is:

```
nenh_new_status_6  (min)                  (max)                  
-----------------------------------------------------------------
SCHED DT           201808080201230        201808080201230
STANDBY            201807230051354        201807230104731
PRODUCTIVE         201807230031912        201807230044208
STANDBY            201807230021546        201807230031138
PRODUCTIVE         201807230005414        201807230013707
```

I have no idea how to do this.  I have been trying to research all morning.  Finally deciding to post here.  Thanks, Kent

Answer (score 1):

```
select nenh_new_status_6,
    min(nenh_trans_date*10000000+nenh_trans_time), 
    max(nenh_trans_date*10000000+nenh_trans_time)
from ntcenh
group by nenh_new_status_6
```

Comment: This does not do what I am asking.  It does not keep the chronological groupings.  Notice how there are two different STANDBY and PRODUCTIVE in my desired output.  Thanks.

Comment: Oh right. That's a bit hard. Maybe you want to use a cursor to achieve this.

Answer (score 0):

If your Informix version is recent enough you can try using the following, making use of the OLAP window expressions.

```
-- The setup
CREATE TABLE ntcenh
(
    nenh_entity       CHAR(10)
  , nenh_trans_date   INTEGER
  , nenh_trans_time   INTEGER
  , nenh_new_status_6 CHAR(10)
);
INSERT INTO ntcenh VALUES ('EDNSB002', 20180808, 201230, 'SCHED DT');
INSERT INTO ntcenh VALUES ('EDNSB002', 20180723, 104731, 'STANDBY');
INSERT INTO ntcenh VALUES ('EDNSB002', 20180723, 101747, 'STANDBY');
INSERT INTO ntcenh VALUES ('EDNSB002', 20180723,  83237, 'STANDBY');
INSERT INTO ntcenh VALUES ('EDNSB002', 20180723,  80252, 'STANDBY');
INSERT INTO ntcenh VALUES ('EDNSB002', 20180723,  62250, 'STANDBY');
INSERT INTO ntcenh VALUES ('EDNSB002', 20180723,  55311, 'STANDBY');
INSERT INTO ntcenh VALUES ('EDNSB002', 20180723,  54329, 'STANDBY');
INSERT INTO ntcenh VALUES ('EDNSB002', 20180723,  51354, 'STANDBY');
INSERT INTO ntcenh VALUES ('EDNSB002', 20180723,  44208, 'PRODUCTIVE');
INSERT INTO ntcenh VALUES ('EDNSB002', 20180723,  42728, 'PRODUCTIVE');
INSERT INTO ntcenh VALUES ('EDNSB002', 20180723,  40551, 'PRODUCTIVE');
INSERT INTO ntcenh VALUES ('EDNSB002', 20180723,  35112, 'PRODUCTIVE');
INSERT INTO ntcenh VALUES ('EDNSB002', 20180723,  31912, 'PRODUCTIVE');
INSERT INTO ntcenh VALUES ('EDNSB002', 20180723,  31138, 'STANDBY');
INSERT INTO ntcenh VALUES ('EDNSB002', 20180723,  23411, 'STANDBY');
INSERT INTO ntcenh VALUES ('EDNSB002', 20180723,  21546, 'STANDBY');
INSERT INTO ntcenh VALUES ('EDNSB002', 20180723,  13707, 'PRODUCTIVE');
INSERT INTO ntcenh VALUES ('EDNSB002', 20180723,  11322, 'PRODUCTIVE');
INSERT INTO ntcenh VALUES ('EDNSB002', 20180723,   5414, 'PRODUCTIVE');
```

And the query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
      vt2.nenh_new_status_6
    , MIN(vt2.nenh_datetime) 
            OVER(PARTITION BY vt2.status_group) AS min_nenh_datetime
    , MAX(vt2.nenh_datetime) 
            OVER(PARTITION BY vt2.status_group) AS max_nenh_datetime
FROM
(
SELECT
      vt1.nenh_new_status_6
    , vt1.nenh_datetime
    , SUM(vt1.changed) OVER (ORDER BY vt1.nenh_datetime DESC) AS status_group
FROM
(
SELECT
      nenh_new_status_6
    , nenh_trans_date * 10000000 + nenh_trans_time AS nenh_datetime
    , DECODE(LAG(nenh_new_status_6) OVER (ORDER BY nenh_trans_date * 10000000 + nenh_trans_time DESC)
        , nenh_new_status_6, 0
        , 1) AS changed
FROM
    ntcenh
ORDER BY
    nenh_datetime DESC
) AS vt1
ORDER BY
    vt1.nenh_datetime DESC
) AS vt2
ORDER BY
    min_nenh_datetime DESC;
```

The results:

```
nenh_new_status_6 min_nenh_datetime max_nenh_datetime

SCHED DT            201808080201230   201808080201230
STANDBY             201807230051354   201807230104731
PRODUCTIVE          201807230031912   201807230044208
STANDBY             201807230021546   201807230031138
PRODUCTIVE          201807230005414   201807230013707
```

In virtual table `vt1` I am using using the `LAG` function to compare `nenh_new_status_6` with the previous row, ordered by calculated time. If they are equal, I assign zero to column `changed`, otherwise I assign 1.
In virtual table `vt2` I calculate the cumulative sum of column `changed`, so I have the different value for each range of `nenh_new_status_6` in column `status_group`.
Finally I calculate the `MIN` and `MAX` values of `nenh_datetime` for each `status_group`.

I may have over complicated the solution, but it does seem to give the results you want.